# QTime to QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer, qtime

How can I transform QTime to QTimer so I could print the left time to `qDebug`?
Here's some code:

```
QTime time = QTime::fromString("23:54", "hh:mm");
```

How can I  take one second away from time every second and print the left time to `qDebug`?

Comment: Do you want to print the time every second?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use a `QTimer` that triggers every second, then you must decrease the time with `addSecs(-1)` and print it in an appropriate format:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer timer;

    QTime time = QTime::fromString("23:54", "hh:mm");

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&time](){
        time = time.addSecs(-1);
        qDebug()<<time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    });
    timer.start(1000);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I meant I wanna print every second from a time to 0. Example: I wanna print  from an hour to 0 seconds. Thanks

Comment: @JoeDoe for example, if you put 12:30:04, you should print 12:30:03, then 12:30:02, etc. I am right?

Comment: Yes you are! That's what I want.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!